# Is it possible to send a book purchased from Amazon to all of my devices at once?

Tags: kindle, ebook-management, amazon

When I purchase a book from the [Kindle Store](http://www.amazon.com/Kindle-eBooks/), it asks me which device I want it delivered to. I know I can send it to multiple devices by managing my library. Is there a setting to have every purchase automatically delivered to all registered Kindle devices instead of doing it one at a time?

Answer (score 6):

According to the [Kindle support forums](http://www.amazon.com/forum/kindle?_encoding=UTF8&cdForum=Fx1D7SY3BVSESG&cdThread=Tx17DN9UC2VK8BF), after purchasing a book, you will be presented with an option to send the book to additional Kindle devices. You will need to do this for each of the devices you would like to send the book to - there is no option to send it to all of them.

Also, keep in mind that most books limit the number of devices that they may be downloaded to - therefore sending a book to more Kindles than the book allows would be impossible anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I buy books on Amazon and usually for every device I have to explicitly select the device to send the book to that device. 
If I have 3 devices listed like this:
1) Kindle
2) Android 
3) iPhone

Then I have to select all of them one by one and send the book to them. So far there is no option to send to all of them at once.