# How to discover/work around a limited number of devices for Kindle ebooks?

Tags: kindle, drm, amazon

After reading Nathan's answer to [this question](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/36/any-way-to-have-amazon-com-automatically-send-to-all-my-kindle-devices), I was surprised that there was a limit on the number of devices you can download book to.  I'm assuming this is controlled by Amazon but I would like to find the details on this.

If you download to one device and then hit the limit is it possible to 'officially remove' the book from one device so you can read it on another, newer device?

Also, is there a way to see how many 'devices are remaining' for an ebook or when purchasing an ebook is there a way to see how many devices it supports?

Comment: Can you change the title into a question, and make it more strongly related to your at-length question(s)?

Comment: @JoeGolton Thanks for the prompt. It has been updated.

Comment: I think this question has to be explicitly for Kindle  as other providers will differ. So edit the title etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To keep within the limit, you may want to deregister an old device that you no longer read on (for instance, you may have put the Kindle reading app on a laptop that you've since replaced).

To do this, simply log into your Amazon account and choose *Manage Your Kindle* (the link is located in the *Digital Content* section of **Your Account** page). You'll find *Manage Your Devices* in the options listed under *Your Kindle Account*_. When you select any of the devices you've read from, a "Deregister" link is available that removed the device from your list.

Comment: May I suggest expanding on this answer?  It's not clear that deregistering is what the question is looking to accomplish.  (I have a Kindle and read on several computers and an iPod via the Kindle app.  Yet I have no devices listed in my Amazon Appstore account.  My devices are listed under my Kindle account.)  While the link is the ultimate authority on how to do this, there's no guarantee that Amazon won't move that page.  Answers should be as self-contained as possible, so it wouldn't hurt to quote the instructions here.

Comment: @Jon Ericson: took your suggestion and also tried to remove the ambiguity between one's Kindle Account and any other Amazon area.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Because of this, I deregistered some of my Kindle apps and suddenly I could download an ebook I was unable to download previously (because of running out of licenses).

Comment: But what if I actually use more devices than the license limit for a particular book allows? It's not that uncommon. I do regularly read Kindle books on six different devices including the Cloud Reader. For one particular book with a license limit of five I'm just out of luck and genuinely limited in consuming the content I paid for :'‑(

Answer (score 6):

[As stated in Consumerist](http://consumerist.com/2009/06/23/amazon-tries-to-clarify-download-limits-for-kindle-books-doesnt-quite-succeed/), as far as Amazon goes (the rules are usually similar [not identical] for B&N):

> - You can download a book an unlimited number of times.
> - In most cases, you can download the book to 6 devices. If you need to download it to more devices than that, you can request that Amazon
>     release additional licenses for the book. According to Dan’s *[their contact]* recap of
>     the conversation, Amazon promises nothing. But you can ask and they’ll
>     probably oblige.
> - Then there are the “other” cases, where a publisher sets the number of simultaneous devices to a lower limit. The following is from an
>     email Dan received from Amazon’s customer support: “Publishers choose
>     whether they apply DRM to their content and thus determine how many
>     copies of each title can be downloaded to different Kindle devices at
>     the same time.”
> - There’s no way to find out this limit prior to buying the book.
> - Releasing new licenses requires that all of your current device licenses be removed, so you’ll have to start over and re-download them
>     to all devices again.

You should be able to remove a book from one device and download onto another after reaching your limit as long as both devices are connected to the internet, but there's no guarantee. There does not seem to be a way to see how many devices are left.